# How do you use memcache with PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I finally got memcache running on my home pc so I can start developing with it at last!

I am not off to a good start though I am trying to use the code on

[php.net @ memcache-set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-set.php) 
I am unable to get either example code to work that they post

**I tried this:**

```
<?php
/* procedural API */
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);
memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'var_key', 'some variable', 0, 30);
echo memcache_get($memcache_obj, 'var_key');
?>
```

---

**And then**

```
<?php
/* OO API */
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('memcache_host', 11211);
$memcache_obj->set('var_key', 'some really big variable', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 50);
echo $memcache_obj->get('var_key');
?>
```

---

**And got these errors from the code above;**

```
Warning: Memcache::connect() [memcache.connect]: Can't connect to memcache_host:11211, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) in C:\webserver\htdocs\test\memcache\index.php on line 36

Warning: Memcache::set() [memcache.set]: Failed to extract 'connection' variable from object in C:\webserver\htdocs\test\memcache\index.php on line 42

Warning: Memcache::get() [memcache.get]: Failed to extract 'connection' variable from object in C:\webserver\htdocs\test\memcache\index.php on line 44
```

---

**I then found this code on the net somewhere and it does work**

```
<?php
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;
// add cache
$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 30) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 30 seconds)<br/>\n";
// get cache
$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";
var_dump($get_result);
?>
```

---

**How can I get the examples from PHP.net to work though?**

---

**Also I would love to see any emample code involving memcache you might want to share I would really appreciate seeing some working examples**

Comment: Is memcache set up with the default port number (11211), and is it set to listen on all the interfaces?

Comment: here are my seting [Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211

Comment: that is the only settings that I have since I am using a windows version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do realise that you need to replace "memcache_host" with your hostname and/or localhost? Or am I missing the point completly? Also, try to `telnet localhost 11211` and then `telnet your-memcache-host-name 11211` and see if you get the same result (you should).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Memcached with PHP for a database query, here is an example of what I used:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$qry = QUERY;
$C = connection to ur database;
findValue($qry, $c);

    function findValue($qry,$c)
    {
        $id = md5($qry);

         if ($gotten = $memcache->get($id)) {
               echo $id." retrieved from memcached </br> ";
               return $gotten;
         } else {
             ### Daemon running but it was NOT cached
             echo  " from database (was NOT cached)";
             # Never mind - fetch it and store for next time!
             $gotten = dbfetch($qry,$c);
             $memcache->set($id,$gotten);
             return $gotten;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using menarche with php for reducing my database hit by doing some thing like this

```
    $memcache = new Memcache;

    //Ip address and and port number.
    $memcache->connect('192.168.xxx.xxx', 'xxxx');

    //Fetching data from memcache server
    $arrobj = $memcache->get("arrobj");

    if( false == is_array( $arrobj ) ) {

       $arrobj = data retrieve from Database.

       //Storing data in memcache server for 100 sec.
       $memcache->set( "arrobj", $arrobj, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 100 );
    }
```

Also you can get the examples at http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php !!